# set a timer in java have compile time error

Tags: java, timer

compile time error:

constructor Timer in class Timer cannot be applied to given types
`Timer timer = new Timer();`

how can this be solved?

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class testNotification{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
            }

        }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question and mark code as code. And provide the compile time error message.

Comment: I suggest you to read Help Center before posting questions, so you can get answers instead of downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer-int-java.awt.event.ActionListener-), which needs a `long` and an `ActionListener` as constructor arguments and does not have a `schedule` method. It seems that you meant to use a [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) instead based on the code you provided.

So change `import javax.swing.Timer` to `import java.util.Timer` and you should be fine.

The `schedule` method that you use will execute the task just once. If you want the task to be executed multiple times, you should consider using either [this `schedule` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-) or the [`scheduleAtFixedRate` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-) depending on your needs.

Comment: thats solved the error thanx very much..but why its not repeated my action that i writted in run method? its repeat one time :(

Answer (score 0):

The javax.swing.Timer class takes two arguments,

```
int delay, ActionListener listener
```

so the Timer constructor should be:

```
int delay;
ActionListener aL; 
Timer timer = Timer(delay, aL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are invoking the Timer() constructing wrongly, take a look on it's API

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Are you sure, you need to use javax.swing.Timer or any other Timer?